# Как вставить изображение и текст в таблицу

Tags: jtable, изображения, java

Как в ячейку таблицы `jTable` вставить изображение и текст?

Answer (score 1):

Для изображения

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.gif");
table.setValueAt(icon, row, column);
```

Comment: Но так я добавлю только изображение, а мне нужен и текст

Answer (score 0):

Переопределить у ImageIcon paintIcon и можно рисовать все что душе угодно :-), включая текст...

Comment: @kff, всё-таки это ответ. Остроумный, предлагающий хитровывернутое решение, но ответ. Такие заслуживают в худшем случае минусов, но не удаления.

Answer (score 0):

Метод void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) для таблицы.
Делаешь панель, на нее добавляешь все что нужно (картинку, текст, кнопку, ...), можешь расположение на панели задать. Потом эту панель добавляешь как объект в setValueAt в нужную ячейку таблицы.